# How to add validation to intlTelInput

Tags: html, validation

I am quite new to this HTML Input Control.
So I want to add "required" attribute to intlTelInput control. Adding the attribute in conventional way i.e

```
<input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile-number" required="required">
```

is not working.

Can anyone guide me through the process of adding validation to this control.

I have included following css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/intl-tel/css/intltelinput.min.css">
```

Then added the control:

```
<label>Enter your mobile number</label>
<input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile-number" required="required">
```

And then at end of file I included the script file:

```
<script src="assets/plugins/intl-tel/js/intltelinput.min.js"></script>
```

To add default country I have added following js:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (typeof $.fn.intlTelInput !== 'undefined') {
            $("#mobile-number").intlTelInput({
                defaultCountry: "in",
                preferredCountries: ["in"]
            });
        }
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the error is somewhere else because your example is correct so you should add the complete code to help you.

Comment: @ricopo edited my question. Let me know where I am doing mistake

Comment: The required is working for me with your code: https://codepen.io/ricopo/pen/pPwwPe

Comment: Thanks @ricopo. Its working after upgrading the script files for jquery and intlTelInput

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

- change type to text
- add only a required attribute

Notes: You could use the `pattern` attribute for phone number in case you need it.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile-number" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but as per the requirements I only want to add "required" validation and not pattern matching thing. Thus the control should contain only value and not a pattern specific value.

Comment: @SailiJaguste I made an edit to my answer, just remove pattern and only use require.

Comment: That still didn't work. But its working after upgrading the jquery and intlTelInput script files. I think that was the reason for this issue

Comment: @SailiJaguste I am glad you solved your issue. If you think my answer was helpful, please consider accept/upvote it clicking icons on its left side. Thanks and happy coding! ;)